# incorrect date format when writing df to csv pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I convert a string to date using pandas.
When I write the DF to CSV, the date comes like '2016-08-15 instead of plain 2016-08-15. Unable to read it as date in ETL tool.Same is the case for all date fields.

Any suggestion to get the date format correctly ?

```
df =pd.read_csv(r'/Users/tcssig/Documents/ABP_News_Aug01.csv', parse_dates=['Dates'])
```

df.to_csv('/Users/tcssig/Documents/Sarang.csv')

Comment: You should include the code you are using.

Comment: Read this and add the code... http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Next you might want to show how the dates are formatted in the `ABP_News_Aug01.csv` and clarify how exactly they are formatted in the output csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/tcssig/Documents/ABP_News_Aug01.csv')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.to_csv('/Users/tcssig/Documents/Sarang.csv')
```

(assuming name of the date field is 'date'